# Problem with configuring virtual hosts

Tags: configuration, xampp, virtualhost

Some details

- XAMPP 1.7.1
- OS tested on vista and xp

Hello everyone. I have some problems with configuring my virtual hosts.
Currently I have two sites.

Here is my vhost.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@site.nl
    DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/site1/trunk/
    ServerName site1.local
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@site.nl
    DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/site2/trunk/
    ServerName site2.local
</VirtualHost>
```

And of course in my host file I have

```
127.0.0.1 site1.local
127.0.0.1 site2.local
```

I have restarted apache as well as my browser various times.

Here is my problem:

http://site1.local works. But when i go to http://site2.local, I land at site1.local.

any idea's?

Comment: Is this vhost.conf and httpd.conf one and the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<VirtualHost "site1.local">
    ServerAdmin spam@a1230912##ad#.nl
    DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/site1/trunk/
    ServerName site1.local
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost "site2.local">
    ServerAdmin spam@a1230912##ad#.nl
    DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/site2/trunk/
    ServerName site2.local
</VirtualHost>
```

You always get site1 because Apache default to the first.

**edit**

Uncomment

```
#NameVirtualHost *
```

to

```
NameVirtualHost *
```

In your httpd.conf

Mine says (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf)

```
126 # Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
127 # ports, in addition to the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
128 # directive.
129 #
130 # Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
131 # prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses (0.0.0.0)
132 #
133 Listen 127.0.0.1:80
134 NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
```

And my vhost file has

```
<VirtualHost "www.whatever.com">
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/whatever/pub
        ErrorLog logs/error_log
        ServerName www.whatever.com
...
```

Comment: What apache version are you using?

Comment: could you als please remove the email adresses in this post since they're not relevant.
Thanks

Comment: Removed emails, done edit about NameVirtualHost. Don't worry, I don't think the spambots saw you :P

Comment: hehe ;-)
Apache version:2.2.11
couldn't find #NameVirtualHost *:80. added it to the bottom. Restarted apache. restarted browser. No result

Comment: Did you remove the '#' character?

Comment: You can't specify a port on the NameVirtualHost directive.

Comment: btw NameVirtualHost is in my httpd-vhost.conf that's where i uncommented it.

Comment: no /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf or similar (depends on distribution)

Comment: Sweet! That took some doing :P Good luck!